# Want to edit Snap Utilities Line script

Tags: python, scripting, interface, add-on, customization

I recently found the inbuilt blender add-on "Snap Utilities Line". I think it could potentially be very useful for me but I would like to make a few simple changes to it. 1) I would like it to automatically reset after creating a face. This can be done by clicking the right mouse button but I would like it to be automatic 2) I would like to make the indicators (that show when your cursor is above a vertex) larger.

It seems like to me both of these things should be relatively simple changes. I have been looking at the .py file in blender but I just cant decipher them. I have tinkered with making my own simple add ons before but not really a good enough coder to parse the code.

Any help is appreciated, I understand this is an extremely niche question.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## For goal 1),

copy the green box text to line 349 in op_line.py

[image]

```
if not self.wait_for_input or not is_making_lines or event.type == 'ESC':
    if self.geom:
        self.geom.select = True
    self._exit(context)
    return {'FINISHED'}
else:
    snap_utilities.cache.clear()
    self.vector_constrain = None
    self.list_edges = []
    self.list_verts = []
    self.list_verts_co = []
    self.charmap.clear()
```

## For goal 2),

change glPointSize to 50.0 in **drawing_utilities.py (line 185)**

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! 

For goal 2) the add-on uses these little square indicators to communicate some information. I have attached some pictures to the original post. The indicators are extremely small and tend to get blocked by my cursor. If I can I would like to know how to make those larger. I sincerely appreciate the help.